# How can I discover a wifi smartnet camera connected to the LAN by DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless, webcam, ip, motion

I have a wifi smartnet camera that works with the v380 app for Android/iOS/Windows and I wanna connect it to my motion server running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Although the camera is connected to the LAN and I can view it on my phone I don't see it listed under DHCP clients on my router's home page.

How can I discover the IP address of the camera?

Answer (score 4):

You can use command-line tool `nmap` to do a simple scan which will show you IP address and Mac address of devices (assuming you know or can find the mac address of the camera). So if your local network is on `192.168.1.x` you would run this command to scan all addresses in the range `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255`

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

Or if you are on `192.168.0.x` then:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24
```

Install nmap with

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

Comment: I don't know it's mac address but nmap found something I haven't seen before and gave me the ip How can I add the camera to motion and why isn't it listed when I run `ls -l /dev/video*`

Comment: "How can I add the camera to motion" have you looked at this resource? https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-operate-linux-spycams-motion/